# Powershell Value Output, disable default

Tags: powershell-3.0

When i open Powershell on two of my servers, i get this value returned:

Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2012 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

64-bit Powershell
Loading SQL Provider

Which means, all of my return true value scripts, are broken. 
Is there some workarround to disable the 64 bit and SQL provider information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was some WriteHost commands in the default Powershell profile - Problem solved